# Row Space Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that *A* and *B* are *n x n* matrices and that *A* is invertible. Show that *AB* has the same row space as *B*.

I understand that the row space is the span of the rows. But how would *AB* have the same as *B*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion these kind of problems can perhaps be better understood if you think about matrices as linear transformations from one space to another. So we will treat $A$ and $B$ as linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.

Note that row space of a matrix $M$ is the same as column space of $M^T$ (same as range of the linear transformation represented by $M^T$).

Recall a few facts:

- $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$.
- Since $A$ is invertible, therefore the columns space of $A^T$ will be entire $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Let $L=B^TA^T$, therefore $L$ is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. We want to know the range of $L$. Then consider $L(\mathbf{x})=B^T(A^T(\mathbf{x}))$. Since range of $A^T$ is whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$, therefore $A^T(\mathbf{x})$ can be any vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. So now it is $B$ which decides the range of $L$. That is what your problem asks for.